# Apply a responsive SVG image mask to a HTML5 video

Tags: css, html, svg, html5-video, alpha-transparency

I have already did a one-day search before posting but with no luck

**My problem:**
I have a HTML5 video in a wrapper with a solid colour (e.g. blue) background *(fig.1)*.
I want to apply a 2-colour `.png` 1440x900 image mask *(fig. 2)* over the video so to obtain, as a final result, a video with some transparent parts, corresponding to the black squares of the image mask (and the mask should scale proportionally with video, so as to be somehow *responsive*)

[image]

**What actually happens**
With the attempted solution (see below) I can see nothing (latest Chrome and Firefox): the page is completely blue coloured and the video starts

**What I tried**
I tried some demos found [here](http://girliemac.com/blog/2010/09/20/201/) and [here](http://www.html5multimedia.com/code/ch10/svg-video-mask-text.html) but in both the examples the mask applied is not made with an image. Here's the basic code I'm trying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <style>

        body {
            background: #5a91b4;
        }
        div {
            width: 1440px;
        }
        video {
            width: 100%;
            mask:url('#imask');
            -webkit-mask:url('mask.svg');
        }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <video autoplay controls>
                <source src="http://www.html5multimedia.com/code/media/parrots-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://www.html5multimedia.com/code/media/parrots-small.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
        </div>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1440 900">
            <defs>
                <mask id="imask" >
                    <image width="1440" height="900" xlink:href="http://copy.com/TCImDzmSoq8CrU8W/mask.png"></image>
                </mask>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </body>

</html>
```

The **mask.svg** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" id="vmask" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    viewBox="0 0 1440 900"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <mask>
            <image width="1440" height="900" xlink:href="http://copy.com/TCImDzmSoq8CrU8W/mask.png"></image>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I'm also open to evaluate a different approach to obtain the same effect.

Thank you in advance guys

Comment: The HTML5 Multimedia book example you mentioned doesn't use an image, but this one does: http://www.html5multimedia.com/code/ch10/svg-video-mask-external-source.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert your mask in pure SVG, it will work line in this demo http://jsbin.com/xejiko/1/edit
The svg is at http://jsbin.com/laday/1/edit

This is the **mask.svg**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 899" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Group" transform="translate(720.000000, 449.000000) scale(1, -1) translate(-720.000000, -449.000000) " fill="#000000">
            <path d="M0,830.648889 L0,-0.00222222222 L1440,-0.00222222222 L1440,830.65 L1440,853.1 L1440,898 L810,898 L180,898 L90,897.997778 L45,898 L0,898 L0,830.648889 L0,830.648889 Z M0,830.648889 L0,897.997778 L90,897.997778 L90,853.1 L90,808.2 L135,808.2 L180,808.2 L180,853.1 L180,897.997778 L1440,897.997778 L1440,830.65 L1440,808.2 L810,808.2 L180,808.2 L180,763.3 L180,718.4 L135,718.4 L90,718.4 L90,673.5 L90,628.6 L45,628.6 L0,628.6 L0,763.3 L0,830.648889 L0,830.648889 Z M1080,224.5 L1080,179.6 L1125,179.6 L1170,179.6 L1170,224.5 L1170,269.4 L1125,269.4 L1080,269.4 L1080,224.5 Z M1350,224.5 L1350,179.6 L1305,179.6 L1260,179.6 L1260,134.7 L1260,89.8 L900,89.8 L540,89.8 L540,44.9 L540,0 L990,0 L1440,0 L1440,134.7 L1440,269.4 L1395,269.4 L1350,269.4 L1350,224.5 Z M0,44.9 L0,0 L135,0 L270,0 L270,44.9 L270,89.8 L135,89.8 L0,89.8 L0,44.9 Z" id="Rectangle-1"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And in the css you call it

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(urlto/mask.svg)
```

Comment: this works fine on webkit and I'm using `imagemagick + potrace` for the conversion from `png` to `svg`. Now I'm trying to make it work also on firefox

Comment: If only this worked in Firefox & IE... https://caniuse.com/?search=webkit-mask-box-image

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about SVG but in CANVAS this would be easy. All you need to do is do is copy the video to the canvas and do the source-atop http://codepo8.github.io/canvas-masking/

Of course you'll run into the issue that you can not access the video that is not on the same domain :/

Comment: thank you, but this library works for images only. To make it work even with video I should copy each video frame to a canvas and apply the mask, not really performant especially on mobile devices and for long videos I suppose :(